# IIS7 Rewrite Issue with Googlebot

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I recently implemented a new handler that serves images on my site.

the old handler was called spotSnap.ashx and the new one is called photo.ashx

i set up a rewrite rule in IIS7 as follows...

```
<rule name="Redirect spotsnap" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="spotsnap.ashx" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="photo.ashx" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

The rule appears to work correctly - [try it here](http://www.sk8loc8.com/spotsnap.ashx?spot=1400)

However the googlebot is clocking up hundreds of errors every day with this...

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
>      at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

these server variables look odd to me (substituted actual website dirctory path for obvious reasons)...

> PATH_INFO /http:/photo.ashx
>
> PATH_TRANSLATED   c:\path\to\website\http:\photo.ashx
>
> URL   /http:/photo.ashx